# Writing screensharing plugin/driver

Tags: plugins, virtual, webcam, screensharing, tokbox

I have been using [OpenTok](http://www.tokbox.com/) for developing a webapp that can broadcast a stream to upto 2500 subscribers. OpenTok handles most of the work for you, but it doesn't allow screensharing - which is critical for my webapp. To enable screensharing, I'm looking for open source plugins/drivers which I can ask broadcasters to download and install, and the plugin should capture the screen and share it as a virtual webcam so that services like OpenTok can broadcast/archive/store it.

How do you proceed to write such a driver? Do you know any open source project which can serve as a good starting point?

Comment: Hi @anant90 have you succeeded in your search already? I am also interested in such a feature

Comment: Hi Mark,
I stopped working on that project last summer - but I realized in the end that there are two approaches of doing the same - the approach described above, wherein a plugin captures the screen and shares it as a virtual webcam, or the WebRTC approach, where this functionality is built into the browser. When I posted this question, OpenTok was still Flash based - now they've moved to WebRTC framework and are doing a really good job at it, including iOS and Android in addition to the web.

Comment: If you want to learn more about WebRTC, you should check out [WebRTC website](http://googlechrome.github.io/webrtc/) or [this very useful set of WebRTC related sample code](https://github.com/muaz-khan?tab=repositories)

OpenTok still is the best out of the box solution for doing the same. Check out [OpenTok tutorials](https://tokbox.com/opentok/tutorials/) or [this screensharing example](https://johntsai.me/opentok/examples/webrtc_screenshare.php)

Comment: Checkout or maybe follow for updates: https://github.com/songz/cordova-plugin-opentok/issues/115

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about open sourced projects for screensharing, but [screenleap](http://www.screenleap.com/api/quick-start) provides on api for screensharing that you can use with OpenTok.

Answer (score 0):

Have you use Opentok below link:

```
https://meet.tokbox.com/
```

and also provide source code on github

```
https://github.com/aullman/opentok-meet/tree/master/opentok-meet-cordova
```

I hope this will help you..